# JS Error Console on PS3?

Tags: playstation3

Does anyone know if it's possible to bring up an error console in the P3 web browser?  I'm trying to debug a site that isn't rendering on the PS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PS3 use [NetFront](http://www.access-company.com/products/internet_appliances/netfrontinternet/internet_appliances.html) browser,try: http://www.accessdevnet.com/index.php/Downloads/

Comment: PS3 actually uses a private fork of webkit that masquerades as Netfront NX.